# variance-covariance HAC matrix - Bootstrap

Tags: r, matrix

I realized a bootstrap on my data, but when I want to print the variance-covariance HAC matrix, the result is a bit chaotic:

[image]

```
tbs <- tsbootstrap(u, nb= 199, b=8, type=c("block")) #bootstrap on residuals
ytbs = tbs
fmtbs <- lm(ytbs ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
covHACtbs <- NeweyWest(fmtbs, lag = 10, prewhite= FALSE, sandwich = TRUE)
```

The data were generated with `rnorm(n)` and we assume the presence of autocorrelation.
I would like to have distinct var-covar HAC matrices for each bootstrap, because I need to perform a Wald Test on each of them. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently estimates a single multivariate linear model object simultaneously for all 199 bootstrap responses you created. If you want to perform inferences on each replication you can loop over this in some `for(i in 1:199)` or `lapply(1:199, function(i) ...)` approach or so. Each model would then be

```
fmtbs <- lm(ytbs[,i] ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
coeftest(fmtbs, vcov = NeweyWest(fmtbs,
  lag = 10, prewhite= FALSE, sandwich = TRUE))
```

or something similar. The details depend on what exactly you want to store.

As you have fixed that `lag` and use noe `prewhite`ning, the standard errors obtained from the individual `lm` (as suggested by me above) and the multivariate `mlm` (that you used) will in fact coincide. So you might even save a bit of time if you do everyting in the multivariate approach. However, the code and its result is likely to be more intelligble if you use the less efficient loop/apply. That's what I would do if time was not a serious concern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, if I want to perform a Wald test (assuming that the 4 coefficients are equals to 0): `wald <- wald.test(coef(fmtbs), Sigma = NeweyWest(fmtbs, lag = 10, prewhite= FALSE, sandwich = TRUE), Terms=1:4)` (aod package). How can I get the result for each bootstrap? When I run this code, I only have the global Wald Test. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would recommend to use the `coeftest()` function for that (from the `lmtest` package) as already discussed in my answer. See `vignette(“sandwich“, package = “sandwich“)` for more examples.